# Slimscroll not working in table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slimscroll

I have a table with one of the td with huge content so I want to have a max-height with a slim scrollbar.
I have used the package https://github.com/kamlekar/slim-scroll

```
<td>
  <pre id="body">huge content....</pre>
</td>


<script>

new slimScroll(document.getElementById("body"), {
    'scrollBarClass': 'scrollcustom'
});

</script>
```

But this is not working, it overlapes all the tr and gives a slimscroll bar for entire table area.

How do I only apply slimscrollbar for td ?

Answer (score 0):

jquery might get it done for you like this by selecting that id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#body").slimScroll({
            scrollBarClass: 'scrollcustom' 
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: not working. no change the scrollbar is the default one only.

Comment: @Raj just noticed i had `Body` instead of `body`, try again with the edited version

Comment: @Raj hmm okay is there a way I can have code to test this on? possibly a fiddle